# Can not inject Repository in Spring Boot integrated with JavaFX

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, javafx

I have project with integrated JavaFX and Spring Boot as one. I have problem with an injecting repository to Controller of JavaFX.

I have annotation @Controller in JavaFX controller, but although it's every time reproduce the same error: No qualifying bean of type 'TaxRepository' available.

Has anyone idea how resolve this problem ? I want use TaxRepository in NewTaxWindowController, but when I has previous configuration with other spring integration I get every time null for TaxRepository.

Below is my configuration:

Maven pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.hubertstruminski.invoice.app</groupId>
<artifactId>com-hubertstruminski-invoice-app</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>invoiceApp</name>
<description>Management system for invoices</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>14</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
        <version>14</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
        <version>14</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>14</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
        <version>14</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
        <version>14</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
        <version>14</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20160810</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.jensd</groupId>
        <artifactId>fontawesomefx</artifactId>
        <version>8.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.193</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.github.fvarrui</groupId>
            <artifactId>javapackager</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>package</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- mandatory -->
                        <mainClass>com.hubertstruminski.invoice.app.InvoiceAppApplication</mainClass>
                        <!-- optional -->
                        <bundleJre>true</bundleJre>
                        <generateInstaller>true</generateInstaller>
                        <administratorRequired>false</administratorRequired>
                        <platform>windows</platform>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

application.properties

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./db/invoiceAppDatabase;MV_STORE=FALSE;MVCC=FALSE
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=user

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

InvoiceAppApplication class - main Spring boot class which extends from Application Javafx class

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.*;

@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.hubertstruminski.invoice.app.model"})
public class InvoiceAppApplication extends Application {

private ConfigurableApplicationContext springContext;
private Parent rootNode;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders", "true");
    Application.launch(args);
}

@Override
public void init() throws Exception {
    springContext = SpringApplication.run(InvoiceAppApplication.class);
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/static/mainWindow.fxml"));
    fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(springContext::getBean);
    rootNode = fxmlLoader.load();
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    stage.setScene(new Scene(rootNode));
    stage.show();
}

@Override
public void stop() throws Exception {
    springContext.close();
}
}
```

TaxRepository class

```
import com.hubertstruminski.invoice.app.model.Tax;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface TaxRepository extends CrudRepository<Tax, Long> {

public List<Tax> findByName(String name);
public List<Tax> findById(long id);
}
```

Tax model class

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Taxs")
public class Tax {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

private String name;
private String description;
private String taxAmount;

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getTaxAmount() {
    return taxAmount;
}

public void setTaxAmount(String taxAmount) {
    this.taxAmount = taxAmount;
}
}
```

NewTaxWindowController JavaFX class

```
@Controller
public class NewTaxWindowController extends BaseController implements Initializable 
{

@Autowired
private TaxRepository taxRepository;

@FXML
private Label nameLabel;

public NewTaxWindowController() {

}

public NewTaxWindowController(ViewCreator viewCreator, String fxmlName) {
    super(viewCreator, fxmlName);
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
}
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No 
qualifying bean of type 'com.xxxx.xxxx.xxxxx.repository.TaxRepository'  
available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. 
Dependency annotations: 
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Comment: I think `@EntityScan` should be `@ComponentScan`, and I assume `TaxRepository` is in the package listed there, or in a subpackage. As an aside, `Controller` in really intended for MVC web controllers, so this probably should be `@Component`. It *certainly* should be scoped as a prototype: `@Component @Scope("prototype")`

Comment: I would suggest using Gluon Ignite (https://gluonhq.com/labs/ignite/), which has support for Spring. This will free you from Spring/JavaFX integration issues.
Application sample can be found at https://github.com/gluonhq/ignite/blob/master/src/test/java/com/gluonhq/ignite/SpringApp.java

Comment: I changed EntityScan to ComponentScan with package for repositories, but now I get the same error but for controllers. Is there any annotation for scan controllers or should I define beans for controllers ?

Comment: Just annotate them as `@Component`. They are just regular Java objects without any special role from Spring's perspective. (It shouldn't make any difference, though.) So are your controllers in the specified package, or a subpackage? It would be weird to have controllers in a package called "model"...

Comment: I added second package to ComponentScan and now errors does not occur, but taxRepository is still null. Controllers are in 'controller' package

Comment: Injection of service works, but when I try inject taxRepository I get NullPointerException. TaxRepository is null. Do you have any idea why is that ?

Comment: Assuming you are setting the controller factory every time you load an fxml file, no: I can't understand why that would happen.

Comment: Can you tell how change settting the controller factory to not every time when load fxml file?

Comment: I found this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38944767/spring-boot-jpa-integreated-with-javafx-service-null. Is possible that reason is in setting controllers ?